# How to get a REST API route like /api/libraries/1/books/2/dosomething?q=params with WebAPI?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm having trouble figuring out how to set up more complex routing schemes for my REST API in a web service I'm developing with .NET WebAPI.  I have some resources with a direct has-many hierarchy that I want the user to be able to query and perform actions on.  Imagine the following theoretical scenario:

I have some libraries, each of which have many books, each of which I can check out, get information on, or return.  The user should be able to perform those actions through requests over my REST API.

Envision the following GET request to get information about book with ID 10 in library with ID 2:

```
/api/libraries/2/books/10
```

Or the following GET request to get the checkout history between two dates:

```
/api/libraries/2/books/10/getHistory?startTime=20130101120000&endTime=20140101120000
```

How do I configure the routing in WebAPI to be able to have such an API structure?  I envision a sample function signature such as the following in `LibrariesController.cs`:

```
public IEnumerable<CheckoutTransaction> GetCheckoutHistory(long libraryId, long bookId, long startTime, long endTime);
```

My WebApiConfig.cs file is simple, with the following content:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace ExperimentalService
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to consider using flatter URLs: `/api/libraries/2` and `/api/books/2/10` or even just `/api/books/10` if your book IDs are unique across all libraries. Don't take the statement "a book is owned by a library" and necessarily translate it to "books should only appear after libraries in a URL."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) if you use Web API 2.

```
"/api/libraries/2/books/10"

[HttpGet]
[Route("api/libraries/{libraryid}/books/{bookid}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetBook(int libraryId, int bookId)
{
    // Code
}

"/api/libraries/2/books/10/getHistory?startTime=20130101120000&endTime=20140101120000"

[HttpGet]
[Route("api/libraries/{libraryid}/books/{bookid}/getHistory")]
public IHttpActionResult GetHistory(int libraryId, int bookId, 
                                    [FromUri] DateTime startTime, 
                                    [FromUri] DateTime endTime)
{
    // Code
}
```

You also need to enable attribute routing by including `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` in you Web API configuration before routes mapping.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot.  Is there any way to define that Route attribute in the RouteConfig?  It is nice to see the whole routing in one spot to get a quick view on the API structure (but maybe best practice is having the routing above each individual method?  I'm not sure what best practice is there...)

Comment: This looked reasonable, but it doesn't seem to be working.  I've set up that in my controller, but I'm getting a 404 when I try to access those get methods from my browser (running out of visual studio).  For example, http://localhost:1287/api/Libraries/2/books/1 is a sample I'm trying and it is never reaching the method you describe here

Comment: What version of Web API do you use? Attribute routing has to be enabled manually in you WebApiConfig? Can you post your WebApiConfig please?

Comment: I'm using the latest for WebAPI 2.1 off of NuGet.  I've updated the question with my WebApiConfig contents.  I think it's pretty standard, but I'd be happy to be wrong

Comment: You need `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` before your routes mapping to enable attribute routing. The link that I included in the answer has a lot more details.

Comment: That mostly did the trick.  Thanks.  There is one part that doesn't work: the parameters for the getHistory command.  For the start/end time, they don't seem to be mapping correctly.  I get an error stating  `The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'startTime' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' for method 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult`.  How do you pass multiple parameters to the request?

Comment: Can you post an example of your request URI.

Comment: Actually, got it.  C# wasn't able to cast between the date string I was passing it and the DateTime object, so it wasn't mapping to the correct function.  I am now using UTC timestamps, so the parameters are longs rather than DateTimes and everything is fine.  Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Glad that you made it work. You can also try to pass dates as strings and then parse them in your controller.